# Set Table Column Width Less Than Content

Tags: html, css, pdf, flying-saucer

I'm using Flying Saucer PDF generation library in my Java code to convert an HTML template into PDF. The template consists of a table with fixed number of columns. I want each column to have a fixed width and the content in it to hide on overflow. I wrote the following CSS for the task -

```
.col1 {
    width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
}
.col2 {
    width: 70px;
    max-width: 70px;
    min-width: 70px;
}
.col3 {
    width: 120px;
    max-width: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
td, th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Apparently this doesn't restrict the column width if content grows above it. The template looks fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in the generated PDF.

Is there a way to restrict each column's width with Flying Saucer PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following style to the table : `table-layout:fixed`.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .col1 {width: 50px;max-width:50px;min-width: 50px;}
            .col2 {width: 70px;max-width: 70px;min-width: 70px;}
            .col3 {width: 120px;max-width: 120px;min-width: 120px;}
            table{table-layout:fixed;}  
            td, th {
                border:1px solid red
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">Col1</td>
            <td class="col2">Col2</td>
            <td class="col3">Col3</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </td>
                <td class="col2">la, molestie vel diam vitae, bibendum consequat enim. </td>
                <td class="col3">s non metus. Donec auctor ipsum in quam bibendum, sit a</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```